# Running rails app with apache - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I got a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page after starting my apache to run my rails app.

```
Details:
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:456:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:323:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:461:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:322:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

other info:

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.2.0
RUBY_VERSION = 2.5.0
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.7.3
RubyGems paths = ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0"]
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong from this? I cant seem to find the solution for this specific problem.

Comment: it's seems like your mentioned ruby version is not able to identify the ruby gems for respected version.

Comment: Is bundler installed? 
try running `bundler -v` . If not then install bundler.